# Filter Parameter from Visual Web Part to XSLT or DataForm Web Part

Tags: 2010, filter, visual-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a scenario where from Visual Web Part I need to send filter parameter to XSLTListView or DataForm Web Part on the same page! If I use Query String then I need to Response.Redirect and that will flush the values of other controls on the page!

So don't need to use Query String, is there any other method to transfer parameter/value to List View?

I have tried making Parameter from Control and defined the control in Visual Web Part with static Id and used as a filter for List View but that doesn't work! Is there any possibility that I can get XSLTListViewWebPart using GetLimitedWebPartManager for the page and pass set Parameter values?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about it but did you tried

```
XsltListViewWebPart lvwpOrganisation = mgrPageManager.WebParts[idWebPartRootOrganisation] as XsltListViewWebPart;
```

and then create a  custom view like,

```
 SPView oCustomView = organisations.Views[SponsoringCommon.Constants.VIEWS_ORGANISATION_DASHBOARD_NAME];
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280376/show-add-new-item-on-xsltlistviewwebpart-programatically

Hope it helps :)